# Método genérico para atualizar Formulário da erro de chamadas de thread cruzado

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um formulário onde é preciso fazer diversas atualizações usando o método de [chamadas thread-safe para controles dos Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)

Trechos de código que fazem isso se repetem diversas vezes. Tentando refatorar criei uma especie de método geral para atualização.

Tenho uma classe para cadastrar os métodos que serão usados dentro do metdo geral :

```
public class ListOfUpdateMethods
{
    public delegate void Metodo();
    private List<Metodo> MetodosPreAtualizacao;
    private List<Metodo> MetodosAtualizacao;

    public ListOfUpdateMethods()
    {
        this.MetodosPreAtualizacao = new List<Metodo>();
        this.MetodosAtualizacao = new List<Metodo>();
    }

    public void AddMetodosPreAtualizacao(Metodo m)
    {
        this.MetodosPreAtualizacao.Add(m);
    }

    public void AddMetodosAtualizacao(Metodo m)
    {
        this.MetodosPreAtualizacao.Add(m);
    }

    public void ExecutaMetodosPreAtualizacao()
    {
        foreach (var m in this.MetodosPreAtualizacao)
            m();
    }

    public void ExecutaMetodosAtualizacao()
    {
        foreach (var m in this.MetodosAtualizacao)
            m();
    }
}
```

É o método em si :

```
//Metodo geral para atualizar todos os Controles que forem necessários 

    private void UpdadeControl(ListOfUpdateMethods list, Control control)
    {
        //Executa metodos necessários antes de atualizar o controle
        list.ExecutaMetodosPreAtualizacao();

        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var up = new Updates(UpdadeControl);
            Invoke(up, new object[] { list, control });
        }
        else
        {
            //Executa metodos necessários para atualizar o controle
            list.ExecutaMetodosAtualizacao();

        }
    }
```

Quando pretendo atualizar algum controle, o que faço é :

```
ListOfUpdateMethods VariavelDeInstancia = new ListOfUpdateM ethods();
UpdateStopXRayTimer.AddMetodosAtualizacao(MetodoComInstrucoesQUeAtualizaOControle);
UpdadeControl(VariavelDeInstancia, ControleASerAtualizado);
```

Porém, quando o MetodoComInstrucoesQUeAtualizaOControle é chamado ocorre uma exceção de acesso de theadins cruzadas. Ou seja, o método não é executado na treading principal.

Um exemplo do que teria dentro desse método seria :

```
void MetodoComInstrucoesQUeAtualizaOControle()
{
   ControleASerAtualizado = "Texto a ser add a um controle";
}
```

Alguém tem alguma dica de como resolver o problema descrito ?